# How to automatically register IIS service into DNS

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2012, iis

I would like to have IIS service running with identical content on two Windows 2012 servers. Servers are only accessible from the intranet.
The goal is that if service is running its name (FQDN) can be resolved by the DNS. So if both servers are up and running both IP addresses are served to clients. If service on one of the servers goes down the IP address of the impacted server should be removed from the DNS after the TTL expires. If the service comes back up it is entered to the DNS again automatically.
Any ideas on how to achieve that? I've read that DDNS is the answer to this but I was unable to find any step-by-step instructions on how to implement it.
Thanks
F.

Comment: Typically, (most enterprise systems) this works a bit differently. You would normally have a load balancer that has a single address (lets say 192.168.1.10). All clients would hit that address to access the servers. Behind the load balancer, are your nodes. So, IIS01, IIS02, etc with identical content. You can use the load balancer in such a way that when it loses connectivity to one of the nodes, it directs traffic to the next available node (failover). If these servers are VMs, you can find a virtual load balance appliance.

Comment: Thanks Nazard, We thought about that but unfortunately it is not a possible scenario, so we are looking for workarounds.

Comment: With DNS TTLs you won't get the flexibility you're looking to achieve in regards to an instant failover. You'll add unnecessary load to the DNS server and network. Instead, use something like NLB or ARR. There are hardware based solutions (F5, Brocade, Netscaler) otherwise consider using a cloud service as the front end. Cloudflare has a free offering though I'm not sure what all is included.

Answer (score 1):

DIY solution would be to use a powershell script which would need to run as a service / or be something scheduled to run in windows task scheduler.

1. TTL would need to be about 5 seconds.
2. When powershellscript is ran it would need to have the implemented psedo logic.

> ```
> if (current host down / some sort of heartbeat check)
>       update dns using powershell mapping the new host to the new address  or remove existing host thats offline,etc etc.
> else 
>       do nothing
> ```

3. Run script every 10 seconds.

**Note: The only risks involved are stated below. For example constant dropped dns cache from a low TTL record would equate to more dns traffic hitting the name server. It could potentially be a bad idea (see below and above comments) depending on how much traffic your site actually gets "if you're self hosting your own DNS server and your name server is unable to handle the extra load / traffic" but it is a working solution.

However an increase of TTL using the same solution would reduce load on the DNS server but will increase the duration that it will take for existing non authoritative name servers and clients to drop their cache in order to obtain the new DNS entries.

This is also NOT a true failover. You will have intermittent downtime while this occurs and sessions will be destroyed and recreated after losing connection with the current machine whenever it goes down. This could impact databases as well which are being accessed and could potentially break other things depending on how code is written. If it's static HTML content though, you will be fine**

Comment: Setting the TTL to 5 seconds is a bad idea. Exponentially so for a high traffic site.

Comment: True, I've updated my answer.

Comment: Let me know if I missed anything.